# \flushbottom not working with moderncv class

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am trying to write a cover letter using `moderncv` and, even though there is no error in compiling, `\flushbottom' does not seem to work at all. At the end of the page, after introducing, e.g. a page break, no additional space is included.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\name{Nacho}{Antón}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

\pagebreak[4]
Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you. Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Given my professional background and expertise, I believe that I could a suitable candidate for the position and I hope that my credentials will be able to give me the chance of joining to the Euro Centre, where I would do my best to contribute to maintain the high levels of excellence of the institution. More details on my qualifications can be readily found in my professional profile and CV, submitted as a part of the application. All the merits stated in this letter and in the CV can be proven by documentary evidence. If you have any doubt, do not hesitate to contact me. I am looking forward to hearing from you.
\end{document}
```

Comment: moderncv sets \parskip to 0pt and so it can't stretch. With `\parskip=0pt plus 1pt` \flushbottom will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class sets `\parskip` to 0pt and you have no displays or section headings so there is no space that `\flushbottom` can stretch to achieve the aim of placing the last line at the bottom.

you can do

```
\flushbottom
\setlength\parskip{\fill}
```

but this would create wildly differing spacing on each page.